# Macro doesnt work when copy-pasting macro button to different worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a function called GenerateCSV which writes data to a csv file. This function is stored in a Module ("Module 1").
I am sharing the code below for completeness, but I think its not necessary for my question.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GenerateCSV(ExcelStartRange As String, OutputFileName As String)

'Variable declaration
Dim Data As Variant
Dim MaxRow As Integer
Dim MaxColumn As Integer
Dim Row As Integer
Dim Column As Integer

Open OutputFileName For Output As #1

MaxRow = 2
MaxColumn = 722

For Row = 1 To MaxRow
    For Column = 1 To MaxColumn
        Data = Range(ExcelStartRange).Offset(Row - 1, Column - 1).Value

        If Column < MaxColumn Then
            Write #1, Data,
        Else
            Write #1, Data
        End If
    Next
    Application.StatusBar = "Row = " & Row
Next

Close #1

End Sub
```

I have also written a Macro in the worksheet "OutputCFs" which calls GenerateCSV:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call GenerateCSV(Range("StartRange1"), Range("OutputFileName1"))
    Call GenerateCSV(Range("StartRange3"), Range("OutputFileName3"))

End Sub
```

When I press the macro button in "OutputCFs", it works fine. However, when I move/copy-paste the macro button to a different worksheet (say, "Guide"), it doesnt work anymore.

What should I add to my code in order for the Macro-button to also work in the "Guide" worksheet.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The issue …

… is that in

```
GenerateCSV(Range("StartRange1"), Range("OutputFileName1"))
```

you did not precisely specify in which worksheet your ranges are. So Excel starts guessing which worksheet you meant and it gets it wrong sometimes. So depending on which is the active sheet or where exactly this code is written Excel's guessing procedure changes, and this is messing it up.

#### Solution

For **all** `Range`, `Cells`, `Columns`, `Rows` objects (and other objects that are located in a worksheet) **always** specify explicitly in which workbook and worksheet they are, to prevent Excel guessing and making assumptions.

```
GenerateCSV ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OutputCFs").Range("StartRange1"), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OutputCFs").Range("OutputFileName1")
```

This is reliable and will ensure that it always works with this specific workbook `ThisWorkbook` with this specifc worksheet `Worksheets("OutputCFs")` in it. Now there is no room for Excel guessing or making assumptions. Excel has a very clear statement and it will follow it. The more precise you are in your code, the more precise Excel will follow.

Highly recommended to **always** do that for all your objects located in worksheets otherwise you never know when it might start failing.
If you have more code go and check it immediately and specify all workbooks properly.

---

#### Recommendation

If you need some support in this and writing clean and solid code have a look at the [Rubberduck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) AddIn for VBA. It can automatically warn you if you have ranges without having specified a worksheet. It would tell you

> Member 'Range' implicitly references 'ActiveSheet'.

in its Code Inspector. Also Rubberduck comes with a lot of other useful stuff.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate explanation. Answer accepted!

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that `GenerateCSV()` is expecting a `String` as an input and your button code is giving it a `Range()` Object as an input.

**EDIT#1:**

This can lead to problems.  For example if `Range("StartRange1")` has the value `A1`, then the button code will assume that this means **A1** on the same sheet the the button is on.

Comment: But `Range("StartRange1")` defaults to `Range("StartRange1").Value` and if this is numeric it auto casts into a string if `GenerateCSV` expects one. Give it a test.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ  I am concerned that the `Range` is being evaluated with respect to the wrong worksheet.

Comment: Well, that is more likely, yes.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I have added the same button code for the Macro-button in "OutputCFs" to the Macro-button in "Guide", but added "Worksheets("OutputCFs")." in front of both the ranges (so e.g. Worksheets("OutputCFs").Range("StartRange3")). I have also changed the header of the code in the "Guide" tab from Private Sub to Public Sub.
I do get csv files now, but they only contain comma's for some reason..

Comment: @matthew did you specify a sheet here too `Data = Range(ExcelStartRange)`? Also when you run this `GenerateCSV(Range("StartRange3"), Range("OutputFileName3"))` it will use the value in the cell `Range("StartRange3")` as range address here `Data = Range(ExcelStartRange)` is that really what you want? Or did you want something like `GenerateCSV("StartRange3", "OutputFileName3")`?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Using `GenerateCSV(Range("StartRange3"), Range("OutputFileName3"))` does seem to work when I run the macro on the "OutputCFs" tab, so I think that does not cause the problem when I run the same macro on the "Guide" tab

Comment: @matthew I've posed an answer to make it more clear.